# Wordpress Migration and Polylang not working

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I'm trying to migrate my website to my localhost and the homepage is not working porperly. My steps were:

1. Download through FTP all the files of the wordpress website and put
   them inside a folder on my local environment (WAMPP);
2. Export the online mysql database and import it on a fresh database on
   my local environment;
3. Update my local wp-config.php with the new connection
4. And run inside the local folder of the project the script
   Search-Replace replacing the old URL by my local one;

When I visit the website on my local server, instead of getting my homepage, I'm seeing a WAMPP page, with details of the local server.I can access normally the admin. There, I noticed that when I disable the polylang plugin, I can see my homepage. If I enable it again, the problem continues.

Is there any other step to make on my migration considering the polylang plugin to make things right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer my own question. The problem that I was having was due to a .htaccess file that came together with the project when I download it through FTP. This file was forcing an online behavior on my local environment with some redirect. That's why I was getting the Xampp home page. So I had to recreate this .htaccess file. After that, everything was working properly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you're looking for, but I use a plugin called [All-in-one WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

I've used it for transferring localhost installations to web, and it works like a charm for me.

Comment: Yeah that worked locally. The problem is that I have to migrate the website to another online host and the site is too big, and I dont have the full control of the host service. Like, change the limit of the upload, create a fresh installation, etc.. I only have the FTP and the new database already created.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've a lot of URL's saved in your database for example for pages and posts which needs to get changed to your localhost URL.

It's not enough to change the URL in your folder

Check this out: https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

I did the same thing some months ago with this tutorial and all works great!

Because you already did the first things, you can take a look at **Step 7: Linking to New URL & Defining New Domain**. This part is about all the search and replace stuff in your DB.

If you needs more help, you can answer my question and I'll see what I can do for you.

**EDIT**

Please attach also a screenshot of your folder structure. Maybe you're calling it not correctly in the URL. For example when you place your `WordPress` folder in a `htdocs` or `www` folder in for example `XAMPP` you need to call it this way: `localhost/wordpress`

Comment: That's the same tutorial that I was following. I did everything, step 7 included. The structure of my local website is like: www/site_name/wordpress. I checked wp-options table for example, and the url was changed correctly. So I don't know what else I can do. But I'm sure polylang plugin has something with this weird behavior of my local site.